# Calculating a GP correlation matrix outside of a loop

Tags: r, correlation, gaussian

So I am trying to calculate the correlation matrix associated with a Gaussian Process using R and was hoping for some suggestions for doing so without using the triple for-loop I have written below.  Mainly I want to try and condense the code for readable purposes and also to speed up calculations.

```
#Example Data
n = 500
x1 = sample(1:100,n,replace=T)
x2 = sample(1:100,n,replace=T)
x3 = sample(1:100,n,replace=T)


X = cbind(x1,x2,x3)


R = matrix(NA,nrow=n,ncol=n)

for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(X)){
        temp = 0
        for(k in 1:ncol(X)){
            temp = -abs(X[i,k]-X[j,k])^1.99 + temp
        }
        R[i,j] = exp(temp)
    }
}
```

So as `n` gets large, the code gets much slower.  Also worth noting, since this is a correlation matrix, the matrix is syymetric and the diagonal is equal to 1.

Comment: I've changed my answer, please check if it's numerically stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much faster using this:

```
y <- t(X)

R <- exp(-sapply(1:ncol(y), function(i) colSums((y-y[,i])^2)))
```

If you want ot keep your original formula:

```
R <- exp(-sapply(1:ncol(y), function(i) colSums(abs(y-y[,i])^1.99)))
```

Comment: Thanks, less intuitive for me to read but its lightning fast in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you could cut your calculation and looping times in half by changing these two lines? (Actually the timing was improved by more than 50% 14.304 secs improved to  6.234 secs )

```
   1: for(j in 1:nrow(X)){ 
   2:    R[i,j] = exp(temp)
```

To:

```
   1: for(j in i:nrow(X)){ 
   2:    R[i,j] = R[j,i]= exp(temp)
```

Tested:

```
> all.equal(R, R2)
[1] TRUE
```

That way you populate the lower triangle without doing any calculations.BTW, what's with the 1.99?  This is perhaps a problem more suited to submitting as a C program. The Rcpp package supports this and there are a lot of worked examples on SO. Perhaps a search on: [r] rcpp nested loops

Comment: So usually the 1.99 is a 2 (this is known as the squared exponential correlation function) however for numerical reasons people usually use 1.99 to enure that the matrix isn't singular.  Plus I figured if I put a 2 there people would say get rid of the abs() since I am squaring the function.

Comment: I see. The Rcpp package can probably give you much greater efficiency than a puny factor-of-two improvement.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to check it out!